# backend controller, magento routes to start page when already logged in as admin

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, controllers, routing

i have a question about magento routeing.
i have created a test module with config.xml file like this:

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <foo before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml</foo>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

and action controller like this: class

```
MyCompany_MyModule_Adminhtml_CustomController extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{
public function indexAction()
    {
       echo "works";
    }

}
```

and when i type in url section this link: `http://mymagentosite.com/index.php/admin/custom/index`it asks me admin name and password, i type it correctly and it goes to blank page with "works" echoed. But if i am already loged in as administrator it just automaticaly goes to admin start page: `http://mymagentosite.com/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/dd5f..`
why this is happening? why i cant go to this empty page when i am already loged in as admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are logged in can call the page `http://mymagentosite.com/index.php/admin/custom/index` you get redirected to the dashboard because your secret key is missing. Notice that all the urls in the backend have a parameter called `key`, that is autogenerated depending on the controller and action name and some random string that is stored in the session.

If you disable this security feature (from system->configuration->admin) you will be able to call your desired url and it will work this time, but you expose yourself to attack.